# Eclipse code setup build error

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, build

Eclipse: Neon/Luna SR2/Luna R
Set
`JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`
`M2_Home=ECLIPSE FOLDER PATH`
`M2=$M2_HOME/bin`

Added all other such configuration: Still facing issues.
Activities performed:
1. Import GIT project (Clone URL)
2. Import MAVEN Project
3. Eclipse point to Java JDK installed
4. Run Configuration (clean install)
5. Apply --> Okay --> Generates Errors as below
Any insight here will be appreciated

Error: -- [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO] Total time: 1.420 s [INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-05T19:19:54+05:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/309M [INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project mail-client: Compilation failure [ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error: [ERROR] /bin/sh: /bin/javac: No such file or directory [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Edit your question and paste this error in it

Comment: Looks like JAVA_HOME is pointing to JRE instead of a JDK ...

Comment: JAVA_HOME is pointing to the correct space - `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home`